Dating found photos
How long would Polaroid photo(s) last when buried unprotected in a dirt backyard? I’ve found some and would like to be able to estimate when they were buried. The photos are still clear enough to be recognizable.

Were the photos in direct contact with the dirt?! I definitely don't have the answer, but I'd think that in order to answer someone would need to know much more about conditions: what's the climate like, what kind of soil, whether the area was protected from precipitation, etc. Also, a description (or a scan) of the photos themselves will help: the content might contain clues, and marks on the photos (especially the back) that might indicate when the film was manufactured could help.
